# Labeling an axis in matplotlib with formatting strings

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put label an axis, and I seem to be getting an error. I want to call the names of the strings I set earlier in the code.

```
ticker = 'RY', 'CM'
```

Then later on I call the names when naming the graph.

```
plt.ylabel('Price Spread between %s and %s') % (ticker[0], ticker[1])
```

But, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Text' and 'tuple'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the formatting line present on your code to,

```
plt.ylabel('Price Spread between %s and %s' % (ticker[0], ticker[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. That was me just not seeing the obvious.

Comment: This also works `plt.ylabel('Price Spread between %s and %s' % ticker)`?